# PHP DOM Xpath - trying to extract DOM from websites - unknown encoding error

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath, domxpath

I'm trying to extract the DOM from a website in PHP and then run some Xpath on it. The code should be simple but I keep getting encoding errors.

I've researched the error message already and tried to apply encoding (as detailed in other stack overflow posts) using mb_convert_encoding() but it doesn't fix the problem.

The website I was trying to extract uses UTF-8 so applying UTF-8 encoding using mb_convert_encoding() function to fix the issue doesn't make much sense as far as I can tell.

Here is my code, it should be possible to copy it elsewhere. As you can see I have tried both ways to apply the encoding at some point.

I think I'm using the correct function loadHTML() rather than loadHTMLFile(). Is it ok to extract the file using file_get_contents in order to feed it into this function?

```html
<?php
  $url = 'http://duckduckgo.com/';
  
  if(! $file = file_get_contents($url) )
    echo 'File get contents failed.';

  $doc = new DOMDocument();

  //$doc->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding($file,'HTML-ENTITIES','UTF-8') );
  $doc->loadHTML( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'.$file );

  $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

  $elements = $xpath->query("*/div[@id='logo_homepage_link']");

  if (!is_null($elements)) {
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
      echo "<br/>[". $element->nodeName. "]";

      $nodes = $element->childNodes;
      foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
      }
    }
  }                      
?>
```

The error is:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlCheckEncoding: unknown encoding
>   UTF-8;charset=utf-8 in Entity, line: 11 in
>   C:\Websites\domxpath\index.php on line 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's a bug or feature, but the code is objecting to the double encoding in the line...

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8;charset=utf-8">
```

If you replace this with just the UTF-8 it will at least pass this part...

```
$file = str_replace("UTF-8;charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", $file);
```

Just put this before your `loadHTML()` line.

Comment: Nice one thank you so much. So it's the code written by the website itself which can throw your script off and you have to edit it as it comes.

Comment: Unfortunately HTML is a tolerant standard, which allows all sorts of stuff to 'work', XML on the otherhand is quite strict.